# Synchronization when implementing push , iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, synchronization, push-notification, udid

I have a very special problem of synchronization with my application that i would like to share with you and get some ideas that hopefully will help me solve it.

I am developing an application that basically does 2 things :

1) Registers for push notifications in `AppDelegate` .

2) Opens a webView in `ViewController` and loads a URL. The form of the URL that is loaded is always like this : `http://.www.thisIsMyUrl.com/UDID` , where UDID is users unique identifier.

In the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` i am registering for a token and after i receive it , inside this function i make an http request to my server where i send the push token and the UDID.

So in both the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` of the `AppDelegate` and in the `ViewController` i was retrieving the UDID and using it as i described.

Everything till last week worked perfectly. However now Apple decided to reject any application using the UDID. So the way to go for me is create a unique identifier using the CFUUID and save it to Key Chain.

The problem :

As you see i make use of the unique identifier both in AppDelegate's `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function an inside the `ViewController`. However it must be created in only one of these controllers or else it will be different!!! (Remember that CFUUID string is created with UDID + dateNtime).

Where should i create it ??? The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is asynchronous so if i retrieve it there , the viewController will make the http request long before the unique identifier reaches there and it will use a `null` instead. The same case could probably happen with the `ViewController`. If i try to create it there , maybe the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function will get called faster and will try to register in my database a `null` unique identifier .

So where can i try to create the CFUUID string and be sure that all the controllers will get it on time?

### EDIT

---

An idea that just came on the top of my head. What if i created the CFUUID inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function of the `AppDelegate` ?? If i am not mistaken this part of code will run **FIRST** , before anything else. So there wont be any synchronization problem as i ll pass it safely everywhere i need it. Right?

Comment: It seems you already answered your own question.

Comment: So my last thought is correct Eran :D ? Well sometimes , writing the problem down makes you think better i guess :p

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: You can provide it as an answer if you like and i ll accept it. Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is the first method to be executed when the application is launched.

If you create the `CFUUID` at the beginning of this method, before registering to push notifications, it will have a value when you receive the device token from Apple (when `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called), and it will have a value by the time you open your `webView`.